# Comparison between packet capturing libraries in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, networking, tcp, scapy, pcap

I want to make a comparison list between different libraries for TCP packet capturing, replaying and monitoring. I have come across several libraries and cannot decide with which I should start working.
I want to compare pros and cons of these libraries so that its easier for me to decide. The libraries which I wanna compare are,
pypcap
pcap_ylg
pcapy
scapy3k
pcap
pylibpcap
I tried to find online and read the documentation but could not find useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to work with python.

Here's a list of the libraries:

- pypcap: not maintened, the last update was in 2015
- pcap_ylg: even older... updated 4 years ago
- pcapy: recently updated. quite low level library, hard to use for beginners
- pcap/pylibpcap: again, so old...

The best choice seems to be scapy, which has tons of options and is easy-to-use. There are currently two versions of scapy:

- the original scapy: active dev. supporting all python versions and high level library for any pcap Apis
- scapy3k: a scapy fork which used to support python 3, but that has not recieved scapy's new features/updates since 2015